# Mongoose: how to filter an array of objects inside an object

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a list of posts and each post contains an array of comments, each comment might be private or public and I want to show Admins all private and public comments but normal users I want to show them only public comments.

here is a part of the post and comment Schema:

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 title: String,
 comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
})

const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 body: String,
 type: { type: String, enum: ['public', 'private'] }
})
```

here is the solution I came with:
Grab the post by id:

```
const post= await Post.findById(id);
```

and then filter:

```
post.comments = post.comments.filter(c => c.type != "private");
return res.json(post)
```

but I want to do it full mongoose if that's possible.

Comment: Can a comment type have a value of both "public" and "private"? Because if no, you can just change the column `type` to `public` and set the data type to boolean (true or false).

Comment: you're right but how to get a post by id with only comments that have the value public: true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your Comment schema:

```
const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    body: String,
    public: Boolean,
    post: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }
})
```

You can use mongoose's `populate()` method to extract the comments under a specific post. The `match` property is where you enter your query.

```
Post.findById(id)
    .populate({ path: 'comments', match: { 'type': 'public' } })
    .exec((err, postWithFilteredComments) => {
        res.json({ postWithFilteredComments })
    })
```